# Whitelist ionic://localhost in Salesforce Org for CORS

Tags: rest-api, mobile, rest-service, cors, ionic

We are doing REST calls from JavaScript in an IONIC mobile app. Which calls the APIs of Salesforce by using a connected App.

On the development machine, we are able to call the standard Salesforce REST APIs to fetch the object details as development URL for app is http://localhost:8100/ and we can whitelist http://localhost:8100/ into the CORS settings in Salesforce.

But when we build APP for the same code, the Standard API doesn't work on mobile and throws the CORS error because IONIC app has URL in format: `ionic://localhost/`.

We can't add such domain "`ionic://localhost`" in the CORS setting.

The only way to fix this to create a custom API and allow all origins for that API.

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response; res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Can someone suggest a standard/configuration way to whitelist the domains like `ionic://localhost/` in Salesforce org?

Comment: Hi ! Did you solved it ? I have somewhat same case and still trying to find out the solution to pass this